# One of Codeigniter session is not set if another session is set

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

When I tried to set Codeigniter (PHP) session in one of my controller it not set if another session is already set.

Total 3 session set and I tried to set another session its not set, and suppose destroy one 3 already set session then try session is set.

What is the issue? I tried but not found any solution.

Here is my set session array:

```
[session_id] => 8ba811200928e06710e970335a7498ea
[ip_address] => 192.168.0.17
[user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
[last_activity] => 1435730720
[lead_db_session] => Array
(
            /* Session array */
)

[livewire_lead_user_session] => Array
(
            /* Session array */
)

[property_details_sortsearchpage_data] => Array
(
            /* Session array */
)
```

Now I tried to set another session.

`$data` is my session value array.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('valuation_session', $data);
```

But this (`valuation_session`) session is not set anyway. If I destroy any set session then above session is set. Only 3 session I can set at a time.

Comment: Post your code.. your lines not hleping

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have multiple `_SESSION` as it's global variable and it's unique. Are you talking about session keys?

Comment: Yes session keys or name. I want to set 4th session but its not set only 3 session key is set at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Older CodeIgniter versions (pre-3.0) store *all* of your session data in a cookie, which has a size limit of 4KB - that's a protocol limitation, it can't be changed.

Judging by the description, your `lead_db_session`, `livewire_lead_user_session` and `property_details_sortsearchpage_data` are rather large and when you put more data alongside them, your cookie exceeds the 4KB size limit and cannot be sent.

There are two things that you can and should do (both of them):

- Upgrade to CodeIgniter 3, which only puts a small ID in the cookie, while the actual data is stored on your server.
- Don't put such large arrays in a session variable ... that's a brute-force solution, not a good practice.